# TextChangedListener Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

**I have got a `recyclerview` that shows a list of items and I'm trying to implement a browser using an EditText.**

*I'm still learning and I don't know the best way to implement it in my code, hope you can give me some advice.*

Should I implement a function which finds in my objects array for the name. Everytime I change the **editText** and add it to the **Recyclerview adapter**? Is this the more optime solution?

---

**ListMonsters.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.AlgorithmParameterGenerator;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;


public class ListMonsters extends AppCompatActivity {

    RecyclerView monstersgrid;
    Button small;
    Button big;
    TextInputEditText findmonsterfield;    
    private static String monsterid;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MonstersList;
    ArrayList<Monster> monstersArray;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_monsters);
        monstersgrid = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.monstersgrid);
        small = (Button) findViewById(R.id.small);
        big = (Button) findViewById(R.id.big);
        findmonsterfield = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.findmonsterfield);

        Context c = getApplicationContext();
        HashMap<String, String> hashMap;
        MonstersList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        monstersArray = new ArrayList<Monster>();

            try {
                JSONObject reader = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());

                JSONArray jr = reader.getJSONArray("monsters");
                for (int i = 0; i < jr.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonObjectLine = jr.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Desem els items JSON en una variable
                    String id = jsonObjectLine.getString("id");
                    String name = jsonObjectLine.getString("name");
                    String type = jsonObjectLine.getString("type");
                    String icon = jsonObjectLine.getString("icon");

                    //Toast.makeText(ListMonsters.this, id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    // Afegim la clau-valor a un objecte HashMap
                    hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    hashMap.put("id", id);
                    hashMap.put("name", name);
                    hashMap.put("type", type);
                    hashMap.put("icon", icon);
                    MonstersList.add(hashMap);

                    Monster m = new Monster();
                    m.setId(MonstersList.get(i).get("id"));
                    m.setName(MonstersList.get(i).get("name"));
                    m.setIcon(MonstersList.get(i).get("icon"));
                    m.setContext(c);
                    m.setId(id);

                    monstersArray.add(m);
                    MonstersArrays.addMonster(m);
                }

                GridLayoutManager manager1 = new GridLayoutManager(this, 2, GridLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                monstersgrid.setLayoutManager(manager1);

                MyRecyclerViewAdapter adapter1 = new MyRecyclerViewAdapter(this.getApplicationContext(),monstersArray);
                monstersgrid.setAdapter(adapter1);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        small.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            }
        });

        big.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
            }
        });

        }

    //Read JSON
    public String loadJSONFromAsset() {
        String json = null;
        try {
            InputStream is = ListMonsters.this.getAssets().open("bigmonstersESP.json");
            int size = is.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            is.read(buffer);
            is.close();
            json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }

}
```

---

### **MyRecyclerViewAdapter.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by Anonymous on 22/02/2018.
 */

public class MyRecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyRecyclerViewAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

    private List<Monster> feedItemList;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyRecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, List<Monster> feedItemList) {
        this.feedItemList = feedItemList;
        this.mContext = context;
    }




    @Override
    public CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i)  {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listviewitemmonster, null);
        CustomViewHolder viewHolder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

        return viewHolder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CustomViewHolder customViewHolder, int i)  {
        Monster feedItem = feedItemList.get(i);

        String name = feedItem.getName();
        //Render image using Picasso library
            Picasso.with(mContext).load(feedItem.getIcon())
                    .error(R.drawable.unknown)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.unknown)
                    .into(customViewHolder.imageView);

        //Setting text view title
        customViewHolder.textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(name));
        customViewHolder.name = name;
        customViewHolder.icon = feedItem.getIcon();


    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (null != feedItemList ? feedItemList.size() : 0);
    }

    class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        protected ImageView imageView;
        protected TextView textView;
        protected String name;
        protected int icon;


        public CustomViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imglayout);
            this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.namelayout);

            CustomViewHolder.super.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View view){
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Toast.makeText(mContext,"hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: searching for "recyclerview with filter android" will yield a lot of results for what you want to do.

Comment: see this https://www.androidhive.info/2017/11/android-recyclerview-with-search-filter-functionality/ if you want to search in recyclerview

Comment: Thanks, i'll try search for it :)